# Azure Services Bus - How to Specify the Receiver of a Message if there are Multiple App Service Instances

Tags: azure, websocket, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics

We have multiple clients that connect to an Azure App Service (WebApp1) via websockets. These clients send and receive JSON messages to/from WebApp1.

WebApp1 sends messages on Service Bus queues to WebApp2 and WebApp3, which also send messages on other queues back to WebApp1.

A message sent by a client, and received by WebApp1, will then be sent via a queue to WebApp2. This message is then processed, and a response is sent back via another queue to WebApp1, where the message is then sent down to the client.

We want to scale out our App services, so that all of them have at least 2 instances. How do we go about making sure that a message sent from a client, is sent to WebApp2 and that the response is then sent back to the instance of WebApp1, which the client has a websocket connection to? How do we avoid the other instance of WebApp1 from receiving the message from the queue?

Is the solution to this problem to use topics instead of queues? Is there anyway to specify the receiver (instance of the WebApp1) of the messages from the queue?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: A queue by definition doesn't allow specifying the receiver since the point is to remove the dependency between sender and receiver. I think you'll have to either receive the message in all instances or use a "backplane" like SignalR does to send the message to the instance that needs it after receiving it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @juunas Queues will not support in this scenario.  Azure service topic can be used instead of queue. Azure topic can provide a one-to-many relationship between each message and consumers. For each webapp in your case create a subscription in topic and add a filter condition in that way you can see messages for each webapp separately.

Refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-filter-examples) for adding filters on subscription.

Also suggesting you to enable session id on each subscription. This will help as unique id for tracking the messages.

Refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-7.0) it may helps your scenario.